# Too many co-authors on google scholar

Tags: google-scholar

Google scholar keeps a listing of my co-authors.
Today, a new co-author was suggested by email.
When I clicked "Add co-author", the reaction of google scholar was "Too many co-authors".

Is this is serious? Or is it a known bug?

Comment: I think this a question for Google, especially since their back-end system is constantly changing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about transient errors in a web application.

Comment: Note that some papers have a lot of co-authors ([example](http://cds.cern.ch/record/205364/files/199003603.pdf)).

Comment: How many do you currently have? // You could ask at Web Applications SE or you could use a different type of cloud storage software, e.g. dropbox.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Web Applications SE.